# In Attribute-Based Access Control (ABAC), how to model attributes from a relation between subject and object?

Tags: access-control, abac

In Attribute-Based Access Control (ABAC), what is the recommended way to model attributes that come from *a relation between the subject and the object*?

Example: medical records as the objects and physicians/nurses' accounts as the subjects. In a simple setting, with no direct relation between subject and object, a rule might state something like "*Nurse Practitioners* in the *Cardiology Department* can *View* the *Medical Records* of *Heart Patients*" (example from the [NIST Whitepaper](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-162.pdf)). Now imagine that in a database of medical records, every record explicitly references a certain physician's account as its *Attending Physician*. A rule shall state that only a record's *Attending Physician* shall be allowed to change some critical property of that record.

How do we best model this in attributes?

Ideally, an authorized subject could carry an attribute "Function = Attending Physician". That would make it easy to express the rule technically, but it would also make the construction of subjects object-specific which sounds wrong.

Alternatively, the object could carry the attribute "Attending Physician = (Account-ID)", which sounds better, but then the technical expression of the rule would be more complicated: "grant access if the subject's Account ID attribute value matches the object's *Attending Physician* attribute value". (In real life, the relations would probably be more complicated and nested and the rules more difficult to express in simple terms.)

Any recommendations or best practice?

Thanks, John

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In ABAC (and ALFA/XACML), you would write a policy along the lines of:

- A physicican can view a medical record.

That is the baseline with no relationship. If you want to introduce a relationship e.g. a care relationship, introduce the patient object into the mix. The record belongs to a patient and a patient has an assigned physician. The policy now becomes:

- A physician can view the medical record of a patient they have a care relationship with.

In a digested format, it becomes:

- A user with role == "physician" can do action == "view" on object of type == "medical record" if record.owner.assignedPhysician == user.userID.

Here is a full-blow example in ALFA.

```
namespace com.axiomatics.examples{

    import Attributes.*

    obligation breakTheGlass = "com.axiomatics.examples.breakTheGlass"
    obligation auditLog = "com.axiomatics.examples.auditLog"

    namespace user{
        attribute role{
            category = subjectCat
            id = "com.axiomatics.examples.user.role"
            type = string
        }
        attribute identifier{
            category = subjectCat
            id = "com.axiomatics.examples.user.identifier"
            type = string
        }
        attribute managerEmail{
            category = subjectCat
            id = "com.axiomatics.examples.user.manager.email"
            type = string
        }
    }
    namespace patient{
        attribute assignedDoctor{
            category = resourceCat
            id = "com.axiomatics.examples.user.assignedDoctor"
            type = string
        }
    }
    namespace record{
        attribute identifier{
            category = resourceCat
            id = "com.axiomatics.examples.record.identifier"
            type = string
        }
    }
    attribute actionId{
        category = actionCat
        id = "com.axiomatics.examples.actionId"
        type = string
    }
    attribute objectType{
        category = resourceCat
        id = "com.axiomatics.examples.objectType"
        type = string
    }
    attribute isEmergency{
        category = environmentCat
        id = "com.axiomatics.examples.isEmergency"
        type = boolean
    }
    attribute message{
        category = environmentCat
        id = "com.axiomatics.examples.message"
        type = boolean
    }
    /**
     * Control access to medical records
     */
    policy accessMedicalRecord{
        target clause actionId == "view" and objectType == "medical record"
        apply firstApplicable
        /**
         * Doctors can view medical records of patients they are assigned to
         */
        rule allowRegularAccess{
            target clause user.role == "doctor"
            condition patient.assignedDoctor == user.identifier
            permit
        }
        /**
         * Doctors can view any medical reason in the case of an emergency
         */
        rule allowBreakTheGlassAccess{
            target clause isEmergency == true
            permit
            on permit{
                obligation auditLog{
                    message = "A doctor has gotten access to a medical record by breaking the glass"
                    user.identifier = user.identifier
                    record.identifier = record.identifier
                    currentDateTime = currentDateTime
                }

            }
        }
        /**
         * Deny other accesses. If access is normally denied, tell doctors how
         * they can get access by "breaking the glass".
         */
        rule denyAccess{
            deny
            on deny{
                obligation breakTheGlass{
                    message = "You do not have access to this medical record. To be granted access, set the isEmergency flag to true."
                    record.identifier = record.identifier
                    currentDateTime = currentDateTime
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: David, thank you. So, in my example, the account ID of the _Attending Physician_ would be added to the attribute set of the object (=medical record). Or, in your example, to the attribute set of the subject. That would keep the policy decisions cacheable: changing the attending physician would change either the object (my example) or the subject (your example).

Comment: But it still seems like it's not possible to express the access rule with a simple condition like "Function = Attending Physician" that would not use a direct id comparison.

Comment: Attending physician is no longer a role. Rather you would compare the id of the physician assigned to a given patient (and that is part of your information model) to the ID of the user currently logged in